# How could I make a function in JS that works like a Upgrade Button

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to make a clicker game and I am now at the part where I want to add a function to the 'upgrade click' button so that when I click it, it takes away 'x' amount of money but it makes my clicks generate 'x' more money

Here is my code:

```js
"use strict";

let varible = 0
const button = document.getElementById('dollarButton');
button.addEventListener('click', myFunc);

function myFunc() {
  varible++;
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "$" + varible
}
```

```css
img
{
width:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="dollarButton" style="

  border: none;
  top: 45%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;

  "><img src="https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/94-940164_button-images-png-button-background-image-green-transparent.png" /></button>
  <h1 id="score">Time to Make Money!</h1>
  <div id="updaCash" class="button red">
    <span id="updaCash_text" class="color-white">Upgrade click</span>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by x amount? If I have $2000 and click the button my money is reduced by 100(say) and when I click add money what should happen?

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to add a event listener to `updaCash` that fires whenever it's clicked. I'd also suggest adding a variable that tracks how much money is added per click. For example:

**script.js**

```
"use strict";

function myFunc() {
  varible += amountToAdd;
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "$" + varible
}
    
function upgradeClick() {
    amountToAdd += 1; // 1 could be any other number you'd like 
}

let varible = 0;
const amountToAdd = 1;

const button = document.getElementById('dollarButton');
const upgradeButton = document.getElementById("updaCash");

button.addEventListener('click', myFunc);
upgradeButton.addEventListener("click", upgradeClick);
```

Hope this helps! And good luck on your clicker game :D

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to use another variable to keep track of the amount. So when you click the button x amount is added and next time you click x more amount is added.

```js
"use strict";

let varible = 0  
let amount =1
const button = document.getElementById('dollarButton');
button.addEventListener('click', myFunc);

function myFunc() {
  varible+=amount;
  amount+=1 // replace 1 with x (value you want)
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "$" + varible
}
```

```css
img
{
width:200px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="dollarButton" style="

  border: none;
  top: 45%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  "><img src="https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/94-940164_button-images-png-button-background-image-green-transparent.png"/></button>
  <h1 id="score">Time to Make Money!</h1>
  <div id="updaCash" class="button red">
    <span id="updaCash_text" class="color-white">Upgrade click</span>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your js code.

So your final `Js code` look like:

```
"use strict";

function myFunc() {
  varible += amountToAdd;
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "$" + varible
}
    
function upgradeClick() {
    amountToAdd += 1;
}

let varible = 0;
const amountToAdd = 1;

const button = document.getElementById('dollarButton');
const upgradeButton = document.getElementById("updaCash");

button.addEventListener('click', myFunc);
upgradeButton.addEventListener("click", upgradeClick);
```

Similarly Your `HTML code` looks like:

```
<button id="dollarButton">
     <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/2/200/300.jpg?hmac=HiDjvfge5yCzj935PIMj1qOf4KtvrfqWX3j4z1huDaU" /></button>
  <h1 id="score">Time to Make Money!</h1>
  <div id="updaCash" class="button red">
    <span id="updaCash_text" class="color-white">Upgrade click</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

And Your `CSS code` :

```
#dollarButton{
  border: none;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```